# Is there a Linux-compatible R/C simulator that works with real radios?

Tags: linux, usb, remote-control, simulation

My Dad flies radio-controlled (R/C) aircraft.  He used to run a simulator called ["RealFlight"](http://www.realflight.com/new/index.html) which allowed him to connect his actual radio to his computer and fly simulated craft.  He learned enough to fly actual planes, but he wants to move up from "trainer" aircraft to higher-performance craft.  After some crashes, he'd like to go back to the simulator for a while.  The catch: he's given up Windows and is now running Ubuntu.

**Question:** is there an R/C flight simulator that

1. Runs on Ubuntu?
2. Allows you to connect your radio and use it to control the simulator, preferably through a USB port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[FlightGear](http://www.flightgear.org/)** is an open source cross-platform flight simulator compatible with Ubuntu:

[image]

Flightgear is compatible with this **[R/C USB-Interface for flight simulators](http://www.mftech.de/usb-interface_en.htm)** (which is compatible with Linux).

[image]

Comment: Impressive stuff.  My Dad tried it and I'm afraid he was totally overwhelmed.  But +1 for the good info.

Comment: this definitively works for windows, a friend is using Flightgear with his radio controller.

Comment: That's wild...stuff

Comment: Try running RealFlight inside the no cost VirtualBox virtual machine running Windows, all inside Ubuntu. I have the same dilemma now. That's what I'm thinking will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can find CRRCsim by googling it and a link to download it from it's official site at sourceforge.  I use it every day.

It is also in standard repositories for Ubuntu/Debian.
It can be configured to use your radio through cp2102 USB chip
(in Ubuntu all you need it to select input device and configure channels in crrcsim menu).

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out how to install crrcsim (https://sourceforge.net/projects/crrcsim/) in Linux, can you please help me? I'm running Linux Mint 17 (an Ubuntu derivative)

Answer (score 0):

I use Aerofly on Windows (http://www.aerofly.de). When You google for it You found that there is/was version for Linux. unfortunately I cant found it on official site.

This is how to for using real remote with Linux: http://www.sandbox.de/hacks/aerofly.html.

Comment: We (my Dad and I) can't find a Linux version.

Comment: I don't speak German, but I found installation instructions on this forum: http://www.ipacs.de/forum/showthread.php/3952-Installation-der-Linuxversion-V1-11-07-21-b2-%28-Date-12-11-2008-%29 there is also this link http://www.ipacs.de/download/aerofly-linux-v1110721-b2.tar.bz2 there.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I found that :

http://www.heli-x.net/

Comment: A bit of details, please? Just a link isn't much help, and can be broken any time.